# Let Apache check for errors before RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible for Apache to process errors before any RewriteRule?

I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*).(htm|html)$ /cgi-bin/processor.py?file=$1.$2 [L]
```

So any .htm(l) files are sent to a python script. However, before that happens, I'd like any errors, such as a 404 to be checked for. That way, if I go to `fakeFile.html` I get my ErrorDocument 404 page, instead of having to handle that in my script.

Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
# handle 404 error
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteEngine on

# rewrite only if .html file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.html?)$ /cgi-bin/processor.py?file=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```